# My motherboard almost always boots into the BIOS instead of running the Windows Boot Manager

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd, bios, uefi

I recently upgraded my motherboard from a proprietary Dell one to a Rampage IV Black Edition by ASUS. Most of the time when I start my PC, it boots into the BIOS screen, but sometimes it boots into the Windows Boot Manager on my SSD and Windows loads and starts just fine (this is what I want). I would like it to always boot into my UEFI Windows Boot Manager entry on my SSD. I have tried modifying the BIOS boot priorities so that the SSD is the first priority, but it often will keep going into the BIOS screen instead of the Boot Manager.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try at this point to make it always boot into Windows? I have a few other SATA connections (two other disk drives without boot entries and two optical drives), and this is an upgrade from another motherboard, so its a first for me.

Here is what I mean when I say BIOS screen:

[image]

Comment: @Moab http://www.legitreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/asus-r4be-uefi-bios-22.jpg

Comment: Have you done any research with ASUS? On their site there are 6 BIOS and 3 chipset updates available for your board. You should investigate to see if one of those updates is necessary to resolve your issue (especially since many of them are for "*improved system stability*").

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks, I'll try updating all the drivers to the latest!

Comment: @CharlieRB Just updated to all of the latest drivers and software for the motherboard, but it still occurs. Sometimes it boots into Windows, sometimes it does not...

Comment: Considering this is a new MB, I would contact ASUS support.

Comment: @CharlieRB This guy has the exact same problem as me (and same SSD as well): http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2180594/asus-rampage-extreme-black-boot-problem.html

Comment: @CharlieRB Could it be the SSD needs a bit more time to power up on boot, or is that just a downright stupid assumption?

Comment: @CharlieRB Nearly the same issue here: https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?48323-Asus-rampage-IV-extreme-(black)-boot-problem